# Windows server 2012R2 Missing MSVCR120.dll - can't fix

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I am using windows server 2012R2 and can't fix this error.

The program can't start because MSVCR120.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Un-installing it removes it from c:\windows\system32 just fine.

After a reboot it is not there. I reinstall using the re distributable http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784 and the same error appears.

The developer of the program I am using it with has compiled it with the /MT flag so he just says it's my problem.

I have tried SFC as below with the scannow option

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491008.aspx

I am guessing it's a registry problem but I have NO CLUE on how to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure the missing dll is MSVCR120.dll and not  MSVCR120**D**.dll?

Comment: Also, remember there are x86 versions and x64 versions, if you don't know if the exe is x86 or x64 install both.

Answer (score 7):

I found that the particular program I wanted to use needed both the x64 and x86 binarys.
x86 binary is not installed on 2012R2 by default it seems.
I installed the x86 binarys and now it works.

Comment: Unbelievable, to fix my issue on Windows 8.1 I too had to install the x86.

Comment: Installing the x86 version of the 2010 redistributable (as opposed to only the x64 versoin) fixed my similar issue with a missing MSVCR100.dll

Answer (score 0):

There is information on the DLL available at

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/using-the-microsoft-c-runtime-with-user-mode-drivers-and-apps.

After insuring that MSVCR120.DLL is in your System32 **or** SysWOW64 folder, open up a Command prompt as Administrator, CD to the directory with the DLL, and enter "regsvr32 MSVCR120.DLL" to register the DLL to make it available to applications.